# Angular 4 Bootstrap nav bar not working with dynamic binding

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular 4 and Bootstrap 3.3. With static data Left Navbar is working fine. but when i get menu items from DB and try to use *ngFor Navbar is loading but collapse is not working.

Code Snippet:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" >
    <nav id="spy">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav nav" id="side-menu" >
            <li >
                <a href="#"> Survey<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Event Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Event History</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Event Summary</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Notes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Back Out</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Print Form</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li *ngFor="let menu of navmenuData">
                <a class="nav-link"
        [routerLink]=""> {{ menu.MenuName }} <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul *ngIf="menu?.children?.length>0"  [ngClass]="{'nav nav-second-level collapse':menu.children.length>0}">
                    <li  *ngFor="let submenu of menu?.children">
                        <a class="nav-link"
        [routerLink]="">{{ submenu.MenuName }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: any console error ?

Comment: On click to expand is it changing the value of menu.children?